# My HTML cannot show the picture and css that link in other folder (node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have trouble connecting my front-end and back-end by using node.js. The result is that the website only represent the HTML code, doesn't connect with CSS or picture files.
The folder has a structure like this.
root
-src 
   •picture
      ○jpg/png file
   •css
      ○css file
   •html
      ○html file
-ws_src
   •this file.js
   •package.json

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../src/css')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../src/picture')));

const myQ1Server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const userPath = req.url; 
    if (userPath === "/") {
        fs.readFile("../src/html/HtmlMainpage.html", function (err, data) {
            console.log("Req at: " + userPath);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    } 
    
    else if (userPath === "/HtmlAboutuspage.html") 
    {
        fs.readFile("../src/html/HtmlAboutuspage.html", function (err, data) {
            console.log("Req at: " + userPath);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    } 
    
    else {
        console.log("Req at: " + userPath);
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        res.write("404 file not found!");
        res.end();
    }
 
});
console.log("Listening on the port 3030");
myQ1Server.listen(3030);
```

Comment: View the source of your html result and post in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add all your project files in folder and give him a name for example make it `main`
2. use the relative url like `./folder/file.css` or `../folder/file.css` then add this to your nodejs code

```
app.use(express.static("/path/main"))
```

Comment: I do it like you said but it not still not work

Comment: check this link https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-with-node-and-express-js/

Comment: - when you done it go to http://localhost:8080/path_to_html_file.html